# Java Applet getting blacked out (on VM?)

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, java-applet

We have a piece of software that runs (exclusively... I don't know why) in Internet Explorer. This software makes use of several Java Applets (JRE 1.6) to provide additional functionality.

I have created a new VM, with Windows 7 SP1, and added the site to the Trusted Sites security item.

The first Applet that is encountered is on the login screen, and works fine. It gets a security dialog box, which once ignored, runs fine.

However, the second Applet, when it is encountered, a similar notification dialog appears with the title "Application Blocked", but it is entirely blacked out, as is the Applet when it is rendered on page.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is stopping this Applet from working?

My first line of thinking was that it was a Security misconfiguration, but after messing around with that, the only thing (which could be classed as helpful, given that the dialog was also blacked out) that changed was the appearance of the security dialog.

My second (and current) line of thinking is along the lines of a Video error, and that the JRE is having problems showing the Applet, even though it is running (not sure if it is, no real way to confirm given the nature of the Applet).

Apologies, but I am unable to provide screenshots at this time as the VM in question has been nuked, but that was the 3rd attempt, and a 4th is currently installing. But in any case, the screenshots are not that revealing (its a black box)

**UPDATE**

I am now fairly convinced that this problem is stemming from Hardware Acceleration.

When I load the browser, the first applet error pops up fine, and the second applet error is blacked out.

However, if I go into Tools > Advanced > Accelerated Graphics, and turn on "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering" (and restart the browser), then the first applet's dialog is ALSO blacked out.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went into the VM settings, disabled 3D Support and put rendering mode into software from there.

Applets now run absolutely fine